# Tesla T4 is not picking GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow

I install TensorFlow via `pip install tensorflow==2.4.0`, `pip install tensorflow`, `pip install tensorflow-gpu` separately while creating a new virtual environment each time. But the system is unable to detect it when checked with `tf.test.is_gpu_available()`
The driver version is  `450.80.02`
Cuda version is `11.0`
GPU is  `Tesla T4`
OS is AWS EC2
Look like it some thing to do with cudnn

```
2021-04-16 13:19:22.605167: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_cpu_device.cc:41] Not                         creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2021-04-16 13:19:22.622026: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_lo                        ader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2021-04-16 13:19:23.590887: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.                        cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there                         must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-04-16 13:19:23.591452: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1                        720] Found device 0 with properties:
pciBusID: 0000:00:1e.0 name: Tesla T4 computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.59GHz coreCount: 40 deviceMemorySize: 14.75GiB deviceMemoryBandwidt                        h: 298.08GiB/s
2021-04-16 13:19:23.591551: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_lo                        ader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.11.0'; dlerror: libcuda                        rt.so.11.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-04-16 13:19:23.591612: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_lo                        ader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'libcublas.so.11'; dlerror: libcublas                        .so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-04-16 13:19:23.591657: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_lo                        ader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'libcublasLt.so.11'; dlerror: libcubl                        asLt.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-04-16 13:19:23.591698: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_lo                        ader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'libcufft.so.10'; dlerror: libcufft.s                        o.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-04-16 13:19:23.591745: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_lo                        ader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'libcurand.so.10'; dlerror: libcurand                        .so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-04-16 13:19:23.591798: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_lo                        ader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'libcusolver.so.10'; dlerror: libcuso                        lver.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-04-16 13:19:23.591838: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_lo                        ader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'libcusparse.so.11'; dlerror: libcusp                        arse.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-04-16 13:19:23.591883: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_lo                        ader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudnn.so.8'; dlerror: libcudnn.so                        .8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-04-16 13:19:23.591894: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1                        757] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries me                        ntioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the gu                        ide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the                         required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
[]
```

Comment: Could you run the command `tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')` and tell the output you get ?

Comment: it resulted empty list

Comment: Did you have installed `cuDNN 8.0`?